# Store Android in-app purchases in SharedPreferences

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, sharedpreferences

Is it okay to store user in-app purchases in SharedPreferences? Moreover will SharedPreferences (which are saved to user's Google account, if I'm not wrong) will be the same for the app among all user's devices, which use same Google account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you shouldn't. If the user deletes the app data via the settings, this will also delete the SharedPreferences.

Use the API, to query the in-app purchases from the user, which is documented [here](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html#QueryPurchases).

Comment: Are purchases for one app same across all user's devices?

Comment: Exactly, if you purchase for example on a smartphone, then it would be also available to restore the purchase on your tablet which is connected to the same Google account.

Answer (score 1):

Julian is right, you should always query for the purchases, in `onResume()` for example.

If you did want to store the product id or part of the receipt in SharedPrefs just make sure to use `Context.MODE_PRIVATE` and I wouldn't store anything like `purchaseToken` or `orderId`.